# XAML binding multiple controls to same property with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a text box (text property) and a list box (selected item property) bound to the same text property, both bindings have UpdateSource set to PropertyChanged, so that as soon as the data is changed the other control displays the change. It all works well until I change the property value in code.

When the property is changed in code, generally to an empty string, one of the controls picks up the change but seems to try to apply it's current state back to the property, so debugging the property you can see the value is set to "" by the code and then is set back to its previous value due to the bindings from one of the controls. I have tried various hacks to avoid this but all have had side effects.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Are you raising the PropertyChanged event for the data-bound property when you "change the property value in code"?

Comment: Yes I am raising the PropertyChanged event when the value is changed in code.

Answer (score 0):

My latest hack that seems to work is to use the Got and Lost focus events on both controls to change the binding. When the relevant control gets focus I change the binding to UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged and when the control looses focus I set it to LostFocus. I can only assume that because there's only one control with UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged that XAML/WPF is happy with this!

The LostFocus event looks like this

```
Dim b As New Binding("Comment")
b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus
EditComment.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b)
```

The GotFocus is the same but with PropertyChanged instead of LostFocus.

At the moment I think this is working ok for me. But I'm posting it in case anyone else is facing the same issue or has a better solution.